# Remove punctuation with regular expressions does not work

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a script to remove punctuation from several text files but I saw that the output still has punctuation. There is also no error message. Can anyone guide me on how to make the script work?

```
import os
import re

directory = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test1'
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test1')

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        f = open(filename, 'r')

def remove_punctuation(lines):
    new_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        new_line = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', line)
        if new_line != '':
            new_lines.append(new_line)


        with open(filename, 'w') as out:
            out.writelines(new_lines)
```

The script is modified to be as shown below but the text output still has no changes, i.e. punctuation still remains.

```
import os
import re

directory = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test1'
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test1')


for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        f = open(filename, 'r')

def remove_punctuation(line):
        new_lines = []
        for line in lines:
            new_line = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', line)
            if new_line != '':
                new_lines.append(new_line)

        with open(filename, 'w') as out:
            out.writelines(remove_punctuation)
```

Comment: You do not appear to be actually calling `remove_punctuation`

Comment: I have modified the script in the first post but the text output still has punctuation.

Answer (score -1):

In your script. You are trying to match a string without points and replace this match with an empty string. So when it would work it should only show points and no content. As i understood your question you are trying to remove all points.

This should do the job **re.sub("\.", "", line)**

```
import re
line = "This .is. a test."
new_line = re.sub("\.", "", line)
print new_line
```

Comment: If the requirement was actually just to remove points, you wouldn't need regular expressions at all. But the requirement is to remove all punctuation.